# issue with date conversion

Tags: pandas, google-colaboratory

I have a dataframe with a column of date and time in the format of `yyyymmddhhmm` (example: 20200325343000 )
and I'm trying to add a column of these dates and times to one column of datetime.

I tried the following:

```
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['str_full_date'], format='%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
```

But it's not working (I tried to convert both int and str columns), I'm getting [the following error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zldY.png):
Can't find the needed syntax

```
unrecognized value type class 'str'
```

Comment: Your example date and time doesn't match the format _yyyymmddhhmm_.

Answer (score 0):

20200325343000 has a problem with this format.  20200325 is a good date but the time 343000 is not, unless we have a time 34:30:00.  The error appears right

```
data = { 'intime' : ['20200325343000']}
df =  pd.DataFrame(data)
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['intime'], format='%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
df
```

throws the same error